# SQLLoader wildcards

Tags: wildcard, sql-loader

As I understand from googling, SQLLoader is able to receive wildcards in the INFILE parameter.
I'm trying to load a file like this:
INFILE 'E:\FOLDER\myfile*.txt'

But the SQLLoader fails with errors
500: Unable to open file
554: Error opening file

There is only one file that responses to the wildcard, which means that I'm not trying to load multiple files here. 
Is there an option to achieve this without using batch to pass the file as parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An asterisk used with INFILE means data to load will be in the control file itself.

```
INFILE *
...
begindata
1,testdata 1, etc
2,testdata 2, etc
```

It's not the same as a file-globbing asterisk.  The best way is to supply the filename on the commandline via the DATA= parameter.